# R is treating my first column as a row name column when I don't want it. What should I do?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

The following is my CSV file, df.csv:

```
 Child  Date    Time
 1  9/17/2001   3:00
 2  8/11/2002   6:00
 3  2/27/2009   7:00
 4  11/11/2017  9:00
 5  8/8/2018    6:00
```

When I do `df<-read.csv('df.csv')`, R assumes the first column contains row names when it doesn't. `print(df)` It looks like this:

```
    Child       Date    Time
1   9/17/2001   3:00    NA
2   8/11/2002   6:00    NA
3   2/27/2009   7:00    NA
4   11/11/2017  9:00    NA
5   8/8/2018    6:00    NA
```

I don't want that. Funny thing is, it happens sometimes but not others, even if the first row contains consecutive integers starting from 1. and I have no clue why it's so haphazard. I want it to be like the original:

```
Child   Date    Time
1   9/17/2001   3:00
2   8/11/2002   6:00
3   2/27/2009   7:00
4   11/11/2017  9:00
5   8/8/2018    6:00
```

What can be done?

Comment: `df<-read.csv('df.csv, row.names = FALSE')`, works?

Comment: That gave me this: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  invalid 'row.names' specification

Comment: `df<-read.csv("df.csv", row.names = FALSE)`. Quotes should go around the file's name only.

Comment: consider using the data.table package instead.  Although not the only solution, it's `fread` function is not only fast, but is also good reducing headaches like this associated with importing files.  Try `library(data.table); fread('df.csv')`

Comment: or your could try `library(readr); df <- read_csv("df.csv")`

Comment: @Stephan this worked. thanks. Created a ton of errors but it still worked.

Comment: What for errors?

Comment: Thish is what I got:
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
Warning: 278 parsing failures.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also use, `header=TRUE`?
Could it be that no leading comma (i.e. ",Child,Date,Time") is present and so the length of the header is not equal to the length of the other lines and thus it is assumed that the first column has the rownames?